# awk to fill downward and generate interval separated by & and &&:

Tags: awk

Would like to read first field then increase the interval based on "&-" and "&&-".

```
Ex: If Digits field is  210&-3 ,  need to populate 210 and 213 only.
    If Digits field is  210&&-3 , need to populate 210,211,212 and 213.
```

Sample Input.txt

```
DIGITS                   AL DEST         CHI CNT NEDEST       CORG  NCHA   
20                        0 ABC          1   N   ABC000       0     CHARGE      
                          1 ABC          1   N   ABC111       0     CHARGE      
                          2 ABC          1   N   ABC222       0     CHARGE      
                          3 ABC          1   N   ABC333       0     CHARGE      
                          4 ABC          1   N   ABC444       0     CHARGE      
210&-2                    0 ABC          1   N   ABC000       0     CHARGE      
                          1 ABC          1   N   ABC111       0     CHARGE      
                          2 ABC          1   N   ABC222       0     CHARGE      
                          3 ABC          1   N   ABC333       0     CHARGE      
                          4 ABC          1   N   ABC444       0     CHARGE      
2130&&-3&-6&&-8           0 ABC          1   N   ABC000       0     CHARGE      
                          1 ABC          1   N   ABC111       0     CHARGE      
                          2 ABC          1   N   ABC222       0     CHARGE      
                          3 ABC          1   N   ABC333       0     CHARGE      
                          4 ABC          1   N   ABC444       0     CHARGE
```

Desired Output:

```
DIGITS                   AL DEST         CHI CNT NEDEST       CORG  NCHA   
20                        0 ABC          1   N   ABC000       0     CHARGE      
20                        1 ABC          1   N   ABC111       0     CHARGE      
20                        2 ABC          1   N   ABC222       0     CHARGE      
20                        3 ABC          1   N   ABC333       0     CHARGE      
20                        4 ABC          1   N   ABC444       0     CHARGE      
210                       0 ABC          1   N   ABC000       0     CHARGE      
210                       1 ABC          1   N   ABC111       0     CHARGE      
210                       2 ABC          1   N   ABC222       0     CHARGE      
210                       3 ABC          1   N   ABC333       0     CHARGE      
210                       4 ABC          1   N   ABC444       0     CHARGE      
212                       0 ABC          1   N   ABC000       0     CHARGE      
212                       1 ABC          1   N   ABC111       0     CHARGE      
212                       2 ABC          1   N   ABC222       0     CHARGE      
212                       3 ABC          1   N   ABC333       0     CHARGE      
212                       4 ABC          1   N   ABC444       0     CHARGE      
2130                  0 ABC          1   N   ABC000       0     CHARGE      
2130                      1 ABC          1   N   ABC111       0     CHARGE      
2130                      2 ABC          1   N   ABC222       0     CHARGE      
2130                      3 ABC          1   N   ABC333       0     CHARGE      
2130                      4 ABC          1   N   ABC444       0     CHARGE 
2131                      0 ABC          1   N   ABC000       0     CHARGE      
2131                      1 ABC          1   N   ABC111       0     CHARGE      
2131                      2 ABC          1   N   ABC222       0     CHARGE      
2131                      3 ABC          1   N   ABC333       0     CHARGE      
2131                      4 ABC          1   N   ABC444       0     CHARGE 
2132                      0 ABC          1   N   ABC000       0     CHARGE      
2132                      1 ABC          1   N   ABC111       0     CHARGE      
2132                      2 ABC          1   N   ABC222       0     CHARGE      
2132                      3 ABC          1   N   ABC333       0     CHARGE      
2132                      4 ABC          1   N   ABC444       0     CHARGE 
2133                      0 ABC          1   N   ABC000       0     CHARGE      
2133                      1 ABC          1   N   ABC111       0     CHARGE      
2133                      2 ABC          1   N   ABC222       0     CHARGE      
2133                      3 ABC          1   N   ABC333       0     CHARGE      
2133                      4 ABC          1   N   ABC444       0     CHARGE 
2136                      0 ABC          1   N   ABC000       0     CHARGE      
2136                      1 ABC          1   N   ABC111       0     CHARGE      
2136                      2 ABC          1   N   ABC222       0     CHARGE      
2136                      3 ABC          1   N   ABC333       0     CHARGE      
2136                      4 ABC          1   N   ABC444       0     CHARGE 
2137                      0 ABC          1   N   ABC000       0     CHARGE      
2137                      1 ABC          1   N   ABC111       0     CHARGE      
2137                      2 ABC          1   N   ABC222       0     CHARGE      
2137                      3 ABC          1   N   ABC333       0     CHARGE      
2137                      4 ABC          1   N   ABC444       0     CHARGE 
2138                      0 ABC          1   N   ABC000       0     CHARGE      
2138                      1 ABC          1   N   ABC111       0     CHARGE      
2138                      2 ABC          1   N   ABC222       0     CHARGE      
2138                      3 ABC          1   N   ABC333       0     CHARGE      
2138                      4 ABC          1   N   ABC444       0     CHARGE
```

Have an idea to generate consecutive sequence at start and end  basic level , not at this complex level. Googled lot to find similar kind of solution but no luck. Any suggestions ...

Answer (score 2):

One idea is to split the data into multiline records using the number code in the first column as the record separator (requires regex RS, as in gawk). So an example of one record would be

```
Record separator (stored in RT):
2130&&-3&-6&&-8

Record:
           0 ABC          1   N   ABC000       0     CHARGE      
                          1 ABC          1   N   ABC111       0     CHARGE      
                          2 ABC          1   N   ABC222       0     CHARGE      
                          3 ABC          1   N   ABC333       0     CHARGE      
                          4 ABC          1   N   ABC444       0     CHARGE
```

Write a print function to print the lines prefixed with a number, and call it once for each number that the lines should be prefixed with.

To calculate the prefix numbers, write a function that operates on the number code from the record separator text, calculating the next prefix number (`number`) and also the new value of the number code (`numcode`). Both `number` and `numcode` could be global. For loop control, the function should return 0 if there's no more prefix numbers; 1 otherwise.

The rules for calculating `number` and `numcode` are:

```
if numcode is the empty string, return 0.

set number to initial digits in numcode (before any ampersands)

if numcode is just a number:
   set numcode to the empty string
if number in numcode has one ampersand after it:
   change the last digit of the number in the numcode to the number after the first dash
   remove the first &-n substring
if number in numcode has two ampersands after it:
   change the last digit of the number in the numcode by adding one to it
   if it's equal to the number after the first dash
     remove the first &&-n substring

return 1
```

Examples:

```
numcode in   number is    numcode out     Returns
""                                        0
120          120          ""              1
120&-2       120          122             1
120&-2&-4    120          122&-4          1
120&&-3      120          121&&-3         1
121&&-3      121          122&&-3         1
122&&-3      122          123             1
```

Extended example:

```
numcode in       number   numcode out       Returns
120&&-2&-5&&-7   120      121&&-2&-5&&-7    1
121&&-2&-5&&-7   121      122&-5&&-7        1
122&-5&&-7       122      125&&-7           1
125&&-7          125      126&&-7           1
126&&-7          126      127               1
127              127      ""                1
""               --       --                0
```

Skeleton code:

```
gawk '
  # Global numcode (in,out), number(out)
  function seqcalc() {
    if (numcode == "") return 0
    number = """initial digits of numcode"""
    numcode = """next value of numcode"""
    return 1
  }

  # Global number(in), $0(in)
  function printlines(          line) {
    for ("""each line in $0""")
      sub(/^[ \t]+/, "", line)
      printf(%-26s%s\n", number, line)
  }

  BEGIN { RS = "(^|\n)[^ ]+" }
  {
    while (seqcalc())  # first time numcode=="" so seqcalc() returns 0
      printlines()
    numcode = RT
    sub(/^\n/, "", numcode)
  }
' file
```

Comment: Thanks ooga, I am getting below error, please suggest,

Comment: gawk: cmd. line:12:     for ("""each line in $0""")
gawk: cmd. line:12:                               ^ syntax error
gawk: cmd. line:14:       printf(%-26s%s\n", number, line)
gawk: cmd. line:14:              ^ syntax error
gawk: cmd. line:14:       printf(%-26s%s\n", number, line)
gawk: cmd. line:14:                     ^ backslash not last character on line
gawk: cmd. line:14:       printf(%-26s%s\n", number, line)
gawk: cmd. line:14:                     ^ syntax error

Comment: @AVN I suggest you fix those obvious syntax errors and fill in the missing code. `"""initial digits of numcode"""`, `"""next value of numcode"""` and """each line in $0"""` aren't magic pieces of code but just placeholders for code you need to wirte. The `printf` is obviously missing a double-quote.